# Ontology tree view based on object property

Tags: treeview, ontology, protege

I use Protege and WebProtege and I wish to see a tree view based on a different object property such as partOf. I tried the plugin Existential Viewer that claims, but that errors out.

Does anybody know of a tool that can do this, Protege or other?

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- It seems you need the [OWL Hierarchy](https://kbss.felk.cvut.cz/tools/owlhierarchy/) plugin. It was [recently](https://github.com/protegeproject/autoupdate/commit/552182cc47e13a454d4c9e806c9c7b33a6bc457e#diff-1c627bbbfa47f185b59af2373adab947) added to [registry](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/protegeproject/autoupdate/master/update-info/5.0.0/plugins.repository), you don't need to install it manually. Just select *File > Check for plugins*.
  After installation, select *Window > Tabs > Individual Hierarchy Tab*. **Update**: do not forget to select the property you need in the left tree.

[image: Individual Hierarchy Tab]

- Probably, the bundled OntoGraf plugin is also suitable for your needs.
  Unfortunately, it seems that one should expand nodes manually in order to view full tree.

[image: Ontograf plugin]

- [OwlPropViz](https://protegewiki.stanford.edu/wiki/OWLPropViz) plugin
  looks promising, but it is not working with Protégé 5.2.

[image: OWLPropViz Tab]

Comment: That OWL Hierarchy plugin looks promising. Does it only works for individuals? The plugin is installed, however I cannot find it under Tabs, or under Views for that matter.

Comment: The plugin is listed in the About box, the .jar file is present in the plugins floder, but I cannot find the entry in the Protege menu...

Comment: @JsP, try it on fresh Protege installation and show your log if it is not working.

Comment: I can use the Individual Hierarch Tab now, thank you. Unfortunately it does not work for classes, only for individuals.

Comment: In OWL 2 DL, classes may have very limited scope of "properties" (`subclassOf` etc). Protege is not suitable for working with OWL Full ontologies (in fact, Protege is not an RDF editor). However one could use OWL [punning](https://www.w3.org/2007/OWL/wiki/Punning). Just create individuals with same names.